# Gmail's Last activity

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail

How can I get data from gmail's last account activity page:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O73Yz.png)[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O73Yz.png]

This information is available under address: https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&ik=SOME_ACCOUNT_ID&view=ac

The problem is I don't know how to authenticate to access this page. I suppose I should use OAuth protocol somehow, but don't know details.

I would like to use C#

Does anyone have some tips ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following page:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_settings_api_auth

You basically have to obtain an Authentication Token by Posting to this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
```

The posting data format has to be as follows:

```
&Email=<email_address>&Passwd=<password>&accountType=HOSTED&service=apps
```

Pete

Comment: I think this API is only for google accounts administrators. I need to authenticate to my personal gmail account. Anyway I've tried to get this token but I received '403 Forbidden' error.

Comment: It sounds like you are not posting the data, but are trying to pass the parameters through url. Take a look at this code, it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304337/post-data-to-a-php-page-from-c-sharp-winform

Comment: I'm doing it in similar way http://codepaste.net/shtyac with no success. I'm receiving WebException(403) on request.GetResponse().

Answer (score 0):

The  https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&ik=SOME_ACCOUNT_ID&view=ac do not work now? I get some javascript code. 
My code:

```
 string URL1 = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";
        string clientID = "my_client_id";
        string httpBody1 =
            string.Format(
                "ui=2&ik={0}&view=ac",
                clientID);
        var request1 = WebRequest.Create(URL1) as HttpWebRequest;
        request1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request1.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter1 = new StreamWriter(request1.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter1.Write(httpBody);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse1 = request1.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (httpWebResponse1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream stream1 = httpWebResponse1.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader readStream1 = new StreamReader(stream1, Encoding.UTF8);
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(readStream1.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```