# Retrieve POST data sent from a C# application in PHP

Tags: c#, php, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Having stumbled upon a problem when doing this, I first searched SO to try and find if others were having similar problems, and found this question: [POST data to a PHP page from C# WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304337/post-data-to-a-php-page-from-c-sharp-winform)

However, when I tried the code example given in the answer to this question, it does not work. The PHP script that I am making a request to responds with a message indicating that the POST variable that has to be set is not set. Here's my C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest POSTreq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://82.41.255.140/api/post-ptr");

string POSTdata = "action=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("date");
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POSTdata);

POSTreq.Method = "POST";
POSTreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
POSTreq.ContentLength = data.LongLength;

POSTreq.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

HttpWebResponse POSTres = (HttpWebResponse)POSTreq.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code {0}", POSTres.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine("Response Method: {0}", POSTres.Method);
Console.WriteLine("Response Text: {0}",
    new StreamReader(POSTres.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadLine();
```

And this is the code inside the PHP script:

```
<?php    
    $A = strtolower($_POST["action"]);

    if ($A == "date")
    {
        echo date("c");
    }
    else if ($A == "ip")
    {
        echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    else if ($A == null || $A == "")
    {
        echo "bad_request:no_argument:POST_action";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "bad_request:invalid_argument:POST_action";
    }

    exit();
?>
```

When I make the POST request from my C# program, I see the following screen, indicating that the variable `action` has not been set. Am I missing the obvious in my code?

[image: screen]

Thanks to those who reply.

Comment: Try putting a CR/LF after your post content.

Comment: Changing `POSTdata` to `"action=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("date") + "\r\n"` causes a WebException. Same if I try `\r` and `\n` indvidually.

Comment: You may want to check if action is even set before dereferencing it

Comment: Do you mean in the PHP script? If so, `action` always appears to be null when creating a request from the C# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

It turns out I'd left off the trailing `/` in the request, and the request was getting 301'd, which for whatever reason removed the post variables.

So `http://82.41.255.140/api/post-ptr` should have been `http://82.41.255.140/api/post-ptr/`.

Thanks to everyone who answered, I've +1'd you all.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to flush the stream. I usually do it like this:

```
string POSTdata = "action=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("date");
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POSTdata);

POSTreq.Method = "POST";
POSTreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
POSTreq.ContentLength = data.LongLength;

using (Stream stream = POSTreq.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve it, for whatever reason. `Stream POSTstr = POSTreq.GetRequestStream(); 
            
            POSTstr.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            POSTstr.Flush();

            POSTstr.Close();` still produces the "no argument" response.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the request stream.  See [this example in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx), which is very close to your code.

**EDIT**

Your PHP null check is incorrect also.  [See this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236354/php-is-null-or-empty).

Comment: @Lloyd - sorry, we were typing at the same time.  Your answer is also correct.

Comment: That shouldn't have to do with why the data isn't being received.

Comment: Adding `POSTstr.Close()` (request stream) still does not solve the issue; I still get the "no argument" response.

Comment: Use fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to check what is actually being sent. Then you'll know whether to focus on the .Net side or on the PHP side.

Comment: Sorry for the long time without a reply. I had to go suddenly. Anyway, I used Fiddler, and it appears to me to be on the PHP side. I compared a request to an Imgur server with the request to my server, and the request to my server appears to be in-order. http://i.imgur.com/NjHhG.png